# Why getting error when connecting to remote mysql server?

Tags: java, mysql

I need to access database with remote mysql server, but when i try it, i get an error like this :

```
SQLException: Access denied for user 'u121252012_iya'@'114.79.63.156' (using password: YES)
SQLState: 28000
VendorError: 1045
```

and this is my connection code :

```
package Include;
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
/**
 *
 * @author Ruslan
 */
public class Koneksi {
    private static Connection koneksi;

    public static void main (String []args){
        Connection conn = null;
try {
    conn =
       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://my_ip_server/u121252012_coba?" +
                                   "user=u121252012_iya&password=qwertyu");

    // Do something with the Connection

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    // handle any errors
    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
}
    }


}
```

please, i need your assistance to solve it.

Comment: Make sure that user "u121252012_iya" is authorized to access the DB from the IP address 114.79.63.156.

Comment: The exception code states very clear `Access denied for user 'u121252012_iya'@'114.79.63.156'`. Test your server setup with the standard mysql client and correct it. Try to connect to the server from the maschine where your Java program is tested - that's quite important for the test!

Comment: See also ["CREATE USER Syntax"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html) and ["Specifying Account Names"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/account-names.html).

Comment: @Hanno, how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE USER '<username>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<pwd>';
```

Here % indicates user is allowed access from all IP.
Also, in addition you might need to grant permissions to the user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '<username>'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

And also, the connection mechanism should be like.

```
 conn = DriverManager.getConnection(<DB_URL>,<USER>,<PASS>);
```

So change

```
 conn =
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://my_ip_server/u121252012_coba?" +
                                   "user=u121252012_iya&password=qwertyu");
```

To

```
 conn =
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://my_ip_server/u121252012_coba?",
                                   "u121252012_iya","qwertyu");
```

Comment: In where can i write all that code you gave my friend?

Comment: The first two commands must be done by the root admin of the database. The third command is a change to what you actually mentioned in your code --   conn =
       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://my_ip_server/u121252012_coba?" +
                                   "user=u121252012_iya&password=qwertyu");

Comment: I think problem is in that line . Change it

Comment: Also, dont forget to mention my answer is right if it is correct

Comment: how can i enter to root admin of the database?

Comment: The root admin of the database at the remote server must do it.

Comment: Suppose your computer is root: you need to enter :  "mysql -u root -p", in the command line